# Transferring data from workbook 1 to workbook 2 with dynamic FileName

Tags: excel, vba

I need your assistance.  The below code will extract data from Workbook1 into specific cells in Workbook2.  At the moment I have it working to a point where it will work if I hardcode the file name of Workbook1.  Here's the code:

```
Sub PopulateFields()

Workbooks("BUPA_LHC_Reconciliation_20171018204045.xlsx").Activate
Workbooks("BUPA_LHC_Reconciliation_20171018204045.xlsx").Worksheets   ("Unconfirmed").Activate

Dim cell_count As Integer
Dim twbrow_number As Integer
Dim owbrow_number As Integer
Dim owb2row_number As Integer
Dim OWBLastRow As Integer
Dim TWB As Workbook 'This workbook
Dim OWB As Workbook 'Other workbook
Dim TWBWS As Worksheet 'Data
Dim OWBWS As Worksheet 'Report worksheet, Unconfirmed
Dim OWBWS2 As Worksheet 'Report worksheet, Error

owbrow_number = 8
twbrow_number = 1
owb2row_number = 8

Set TWB = Workbooks("LHC Report Email test v1.1 (IN TESTING).xlsm")
Set OWB = Workbooks("BUPA_LHC_Reconciliation_20171018204045.xlsx")
Set TWBWS = TWB.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set OWBWS = OWB.Worksheets("Unconfirmed")
Set OWBWS2 = OWB.Worksheets("Errors")

cell_count = 0
OWBLastRow = OWBWS.Cells(OWBWS.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row - 2
OWBLastRow2 = OWBWS2.Cells(OWBWS2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row - 2


Do
DoEvents

cell_count = cell_count + 1
owbrow_number = owbrow_number + 1
twbrow_number = twbrownumber + 1

TWBWS.Cells(2, "A").Resize(OWBLastRow - 8, 1).Value = OWBWS.Cells(9, "A").Resize(OWBLastRow - 8, 1).Value
TWBWS.Cells(2, "B").Resize(OWBLastRow - 8, 1).Value = "LHC Unconfirmed"
TWBWS.Cells(2, "C").Resize(OWBLastRow - 8, 1).Value = "Please refer to link below to process"
TWBWS.Cells(2, "E").Resize(OWBLastRow - 8, 1).Value = OWBWS.Cells(9, "C").Resize(OWBLastRow - 8, 1).Value
TWBWS.Cells(2, "G").Resize(OWBLastRow - 8, 1).Value = OWBWS.Cells(9, "B").Resize(OWBLastRow - 8, 1).Value

Loop Until owbrow_number = OWBLastRow

twb2row_number = twb_rownumber

Do
DoEvents

owb2row_number = owb2row_number + 1
twb2row_number = twb2rownumber + 1

TWBWS.Cells(cell_count, "A").Resize(OWBLastRow2 - 8, 1).Value = OWBWS2.Cells(9, "A").Resize(OWBLastRow2 - 8, 1).Value
TWBWS.Cells(cell_count, "B").Resize(OWBLastRow2 - 8, 1).Value = "LHC Certificate Errors"
TWBWS.Cells(cell_count, "C").Resize(OWBLastRow2 - 8, 1).Value = "Please refer to link below to process"
TWBWS.Cells(cell_count, "E").Resize(OWBLastRow2 - 8, 1).Value = OWBWS2.Cells(9, "C").Resize(OWBLastRow2 - 8, 1).Value
TWBWS.Cells(cell_count, "G").Resize(OWBLastRow2 - 8, 1).Value = OWBWS2.Cells(9, "B").Resize(OWBLastRow2 - 8, 1).Value

Loop Until owb2row_number = OWBLastRow2

End Sub
```

I have now created a piece of code that will have a Open File Dialog, store the name of the file selected into a variable called 'FileName' but am having trouble implementing this variable into my PopulateFields function so that it will use the file name chosen instead of the one I hardcoded.  I need to do this because the file name changes all the time and I don't to have to change the file name all the time.

Here's the code I'm using to get the file name:

```
Sub SelectFile()

Dim f As String, OpenMsg As String, FileName As String

f = Application.GetOpenFilename _
(Title:="Please choose a file to open", _
FileFilter:="Excel Files *.xls* (*.xls*),")

'Exit if cancel is selected
If f = "False" Then Exit Sub

'Find Filename
FileName = Dir(f, vbDirectory)

MsgBox FileName
```

Now I've tried doing substituting the hardcoded file name with the variable FileName, but it doesn't work...  This is what I've tried:

```
Workbooks(FileName).Activate
Workbooks(FileName).Worksheets("Unconfirmed").Activate

Set OWB = Workbooks(FileName)
```

The error I'm getting is 'Run-Time error '9': Subscript out of range.'

Could anyone help?

Thanks,
Vinh

Comment: since a filename is always a string value   ...... google `VBA how to concatenate strings`

Comment: The missing bracket was my mistake on the copying into the message.  I've edited to include the error message.  Thanks - and sorry I'm new to all of this.

Comment: if u have the problem in copying line use `copy` function instead of `.Value =`

Comment: You still need to provide full path to your file. Right now you're just telling Excel to open a file but your not telling it where to find it.
`Workbooks.Open(Path & FileName)`

Comment: Thank you everybody, it is working now... I just need to make sure the file was open when I execute.

Comment: @VinhPham Where is problem occurred?